# How to retrieve email confirmation token code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

"**[ConfirmEmailAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn497538(v=vs.108).aspx)**" this method confirms the email.

But I dont want to confirm the email just yet instead I want to verify the email token code first and if email token code is valid, do something and then execute **ConfirmEmailAsync**.

---

**EDIT**
There is "[VerifyUserTokenAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151647(v=vs.108).aspx)", but what is the value for provider and purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
        bool IsEmailCodeValid = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, "Default", "EmailConfirmation", code);
```